# How do I change the indicator menu labels?

Tags: unity, 12.10, indicator

I use `Ubuntu 12.10` and `Unity theme`.

I wanted to change some of the labels like `Shut Down...` to `Turn Off` or something else. Wanted to know where such labels are stored so I can could change a few of them. Is it possible to edit a few files and get this change done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't these stored in some text files, so that it would be easy for translation and all, wouldn't changing that file be enough(if there is a file, which should be the case)? Normally, thought for L10N, it would be a simple text sort of file. I am not sure whether I am correct, please correct me, if the case be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom translation, or edit the code (which will break existing translations), to change the string.

The code that creates these menu items is [here](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~indicator-applet-developers/indicator-session/trunk.13.04/view/head:/src/session-menu-mgr.c#L486)

Comment: Can you add instructions on how you would change this?  Or at least a link?

Comment: I believe you have to look here `/sbin/shutdown` and work from there. You could easily walk the system in one day and find all the references, now couldn't you?

Comment: No. That command is totally irrelevant to this.

Comment: Thanks @dobey for your efforts. I thought it might not have been hard-coded, though it is not, it seems to be quite risky and adventurous and may be i'll have to be content with "Shut down..." :P